# Launching jar from java: execution path and relative resources

Tags: java, jar, path, system, execution

I'm trying to run a jar file from Java code, through exec().

The jar I'm executing have some resources relative to its path that need to be loaded. So for example executing from console:
java -jar [/path/to/jar/]exec.jar
is working only if the command is launched from the same directory

I've tried with: cd /path/to/jar/exec.jar && java -jar /path/to/jar/exec.jar
but it seems there is a problem within exec() for running cd, widely covered on the web. The main problem is that I'm looking for a procedure that runs both on Linux and Windows.

I've tried to mess with the -classpath option, but with no luck.

Is there any simple solution to this? Note that I'm not "fond" of the system call idea, it's just I was looking for a simple way to schedule the execution of custom jars.

Thank you in advance!
CB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the working directory of the launched process using [ProcessBuilder.directory(File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29).